# How to display text with different font-style with same base line in XSL-FO?

Tags: fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

In Apache FOP, I'm using `TimesNewRoman` font to render content text

```
SYK ( 단차 보상 도전 TAPE), Model: AMB136ZH01 REV0.4
```

This text contains special words (`단차 보상 도전` - the Korean language) that `TimesNewRoman` font can't render, so I must use the `UnGungseo.ttf` font to render these words. However, the text in  rendered PDF hasn't baseline like the picture below:

[image]

How to display text content in same baseline?

The `TimesNewRoman` font I'm using [times.ttf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEIxGlF8UacacbcLfYO6ITy2vQUeybU2/view?usp=sharing) and the `UnGungseo` font to render special characters [UnGungseo.ttf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jp25Z8ENXSth84_9qDciTVX01XzwDIJ6/view?usp=sharing)

My `xsl-fo content` file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jrGB7grBvJW417yGDK8YcQLUDfUQoQuL/view?usp=sharing) and my `fop.xconf` file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHp7Dk89w8cFbALPsq5JfuwgBD1c6xh1/view?usp=sharing) and in `fop.xconf` file I include `UnGungseo.ttf` as below:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="component/iam-einvoice/fonts/UnGungseo.ttf">
  <font-triplet name="KoreanRegular" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
```

Comment: That is unusual. Can you include the XSL-FO markup for the two table cell? The '(' in 'SYK (' shows a different baseline to the '(' in '00183A ('. Whatever the problem is, it is possibly also inconsistent.

Comment: Hi Tony, I've been attached my xsl-fo content and my fop.xconf, please help me to find out solution, thank you so much

Comment: Hi KJ, what font did you use to render the text `?style? (단차 보상 도전) [no Latin descenders]` in your pdf file?

Comment: As a workaround: if you are able to capture those Korean words, put them in a separate fo:inline with a baseline-shift property that suits.

Comment: Hi Siebe, this text is typed by the end-user, it could be Chinese, Japanese, Korean characters, so I think it is too difficult to detect these characters